# Variable re-assignment of object reference leaves other object unaltered (no “transitive” assignment)

Tags: javascript, variables, reference, pass-by-reference

I have an object that I want to replace.

```
var obj1 = { x: "a" };
var ref = obj1;
var obj2 = { y: "b" };

obj1 = obj2;
```

This results in `ref` being equivalent to `{ x: "a" }`, but I want it to get changed as well to point to `obj2` to get `ref` being equivalent to `{ y: "b" }`.

Comment: It's not very clear, what you want

Comment: I basically want to replace the reference to an object. So when I do obj1 = obj2, I want all references to obj1 to get replaced with a reference to obj2

Comment: That's just not how javascript work :)

Comment: @ValLeNain That's what I already thought, but you never know. There are often some workarounds I am still not aware of. Apparently not this time :)

Comment: Closely related: [Why are changes in an object no longer reflected after reassignment?](/q/27476421/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. JS passes objects by a copy of the reference, so in the step `var ref = obj1` you're not actually assigning a reference pointer like you would in a language like C. Instead you're creating a copy of a reference that points to an object that looks like `{x: 'a'}`.

See this answer for other options you have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17382443/6415214.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change all the fields of obj1 with the fields of obj2

```
var obj1 = { x: 'a' };
var ref = obj1;
var obj2 = { y: 'b' };
obj1.x = obj2.y;
console.log(ref) // Print {x, 'b'}
```

If you want to add {y,'b'} you can follow the approach

```
obj1.y=obj2.y
console.log(obj1); prints {x: "b", y: "b"}
console.log(ref); prints {x: "b", y: "b"}
```

If you instead want to delete obj1.x you can do something like this

```
delete obj1.x;
console.log(ref) prints {y:'b'}
```