# Why this code references different result

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning value and reference types in JS but I faced some confusion on the below code:

```js
const obj = {
  arr: [{
    x: 17
  }]
};

let z = obj.arr;

z = [{
  x: 25
}];

console.log(obj.arr[0].x);
```

The above code outputs 17 but why? Well, arr is a reference type, that is, it is mutable then we equalize obj.arr to variable z so z holds reference to arr array in obj object. Finally, z holding 17 then we change it to 25 but it output 17.

Comment: `z` isn’t “bound” to `obj.arr`. You just reassign it with a completely different value.

Comment: This line `z = [{ x: 25 }];` does not "change it to 25".... it points z to a new array, leaving obj.arr unchanged

Comment: Try `z[0].x = 25;` instead of `z = [{ x: 25 }];`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [js replace object / change reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814414/js-replace-object-change-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time, you have something like this:

```
obj ---> {
           arr ---+
         }        |
                  |
                  v
                  [
                     [0] ---+
                  ]         |
                  ^         |
                  |         v
                  |         { x: 17 }
                  |
                  |
z ----------------+
```

Note that `z` now points to *the same object as `obj.arr`* but not *to `obj.arr`*.

Reassigning `z` changes only what `z` points to, but it doesn't affect `obj.arr`; it refers to the same object as before:

```
obj ---> {
           arr ---+
         }        |
                  |
                  v
                  [
                     [0] ---+
                  ]         |
                            |
                            v
                            { x: 17 }
                  
                  
z ----> [
          [0] ----> { x: 25 }
        ]
```

That's why `obj.arr` didn't change.

But how to change it via `z`, you might ask?

You can't change `obj.arr` itself, but you can still **mutate** it.

Instead of your code, you can use this:

```js
z[0] = { x:25 }
```

Now you have:

```
obj ---> {
           arr ---+
         }        |
                  |
                  v
                  [
                     [0] ---> { x: 25 }
                  ]         
                  ^         
                  |        
                  |         { x: 17 } -----> Garbage collection
                  |
                  |
z ----------------+
```

```js
const obj = {
    arr: [{ x: 17 }]
};

let z = obj.arr;

z[0] = { x: 25 };

console.log(obj.arr[0].x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {
 arr: [{ x: 17 }]
};

/**
 * z -> it is only reference to original object (const obj in our case). 
 * It is like another door to the same room
 */
let z = obj.arr;

/*
 * now z -> points to other value (array), but previous still exist
 */
z = [{ x: 25 }]; 

console.log(obj.arr[0].x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just created z, which is a copy of obj.arr . If you change the value of z, the copy, the original (obj.arr) do not change.

I'm French that's why my english isn't perfect

Comment: I wouldn't say that  `z` is a copy of `obj.arr`.  "`z` refers to the same array as `obj.arr`" (the one with 17 in it) might be a better way to say it.  After doing `z = [{ x: 25 }]`,  `z` refers to a new array (the one with 25 in it).  And `obj.arr` still refers to the first array (the one with 17 in it).

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `obj.arr` is replaced. `z = [{ x: 25 }];` simply creates a new array with a new object, `{ x: 25 }`, inside it. Then, it places a reference to this new array into `z`.