# Javascript array referencing an array position (not an element)

Tags: javascript, arrays

UPDATE:

Many asked why not using `[arr[0], arr[1]]`. The problem is I have to pass this array to a method, which I don't have access [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table). And I don't want to call the method over and over again.

I already processed the `arr` array and I don't want to process `pointer` array to reflect the new data, which I already know where it is.

The [Nina Scholz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53991321/8038345) seems to solve the problem.

---

Is there a way to use "pointers" like C in Javascript?

What I want to do is:

I have an array with objects

```
const arr = [
    {prop: 3},
    {prop: 4},
];
```

And I want to have an array to point to the positions of this array

```
const pointer = [arr[0], arr[1]]; // I want pointer to point to be an array containing the first and second elements of arr
```

This will get a reference to the `{prop: 3}` and `{prop: 4}` objects, which is not what I want, because, if I do:

```
arr.splice(0, 0, {prop: 1}); // arr => [{prop:1},{prop:3},{prop:4}]
console.log(pointer); // [{prop: 3},{prop: 4}]
```

As you can see, `pointer` holds a reference to the objects `{prop:3}` and `{prop:4}`.

How can I achieve `pointer` to hold reference to the position 0 of the array, instead of the object stored in it? So, on this example, `pointer => [{prop:1},{prop:3}]`?

I can't call `pointer = [arr[0], arr[1]]` all the time because `arr` will change constantly and asynchronously.

Is there a "reactive" way to handle arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382427/are-there-pointers-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there pointers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382427/are-there-pointers-in-javascript)

Comment: Are your pointers always to the same array? In that case, just make an array of indexes.

Comment: @LaurensDeprost I don't think any of the answers there would help with this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? If you want the object at index `0`, just use `arr[0]`... it will return the current value at the time.

Comment: Please put your **update** below the original message not above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (not supported by IE) with a [get trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get):

```js
const arr = [{ prop: 3 }, { prop: 4 }];

const pointer = new Proxy([], {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    // if the prop is a string that can be converted to a number
    // return the corresponding value from the arr
    if(typeof prop === 'string' && !isNaN(Number(prop))) return arr[target[prop]];

    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
  }
});

pointer.push(0, 1);
console.log(pointer);

arr.splice(0, 0, { prop: 1 });
console.log(pointer);
```

Answer (score 5):

If your pointers are always to the same array, you can simply store the indexes.

```
const pointer = [0, 1];
```

Then you would use:

```
console.log(pointer.map(ptr => arr[ptr]));
```

If your pointers can point to different arrays, you can make the elements of `pointer` be objects that contain references to the array along with their indexes.

```
const pointer = [{a: arr, i: 0}, {a: arr1, i: 1}];
console.log(pointer.map(({a, i}) => a[i]));
```

Interesting aside: several decades ago I used a C implementation for Symbolics Lisp Machines. This is basically how it represented C pointers.

Comment: I updated my question. Even though I can hold the indexes, I still have to call the method again. I actually was looking for a `getter` inside the array, but I didn't know that :x Anyway, this is an excellent way to `point` to an array position, instead of a value.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a getter function and return the element of the actual object.

```js
const arr = [{ prop: 3 }, { prop: 4 }];
const pointer = [];

Object.defineProperty(pointer, 0, { get() { return arr[0]; } });
Object.defineProperty(pointer, 1, { get() { return arr[1]; } });

arr.splice(0, 0, { prop: 1 });
console.log(pointer);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like what I was looking for. Another question, Is there a more straightforward way to create a `getter` inside an array? Or do I have to use the `Object` reflection to achieve this?

Comment: you need either `defineProperty` for a single property or `defineProperties` for more than one. ther is no workaround without, because every object would just be the object in the array, not a meta function.