# Javascript pass by reference to be overwritten in another file at a later date

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a dummy example:

```js
const obj = {foo: '123'};

function logObj(obj) {
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(obj);
    }, 100)
}

function overWrite(obj) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('overwriting')
        obj = {foo: 'bar'}
    }, 1000);
}

logObj(obj)
overWrite(obj)
```

I'm expecting to see `{ foo: '123' }` every 100ms until `overwriting` is called and then to see `{ foo: 'bar' }`. However the object is never over-written and I always see 123.

**EDIT**

I do not want to change just one of the keys; I do in fact want to replace the entire object, so doing `obj.foo = 'bar'` is not a solution

Comment: As I said in my comments, then do not pass the obj into the methods.  Just reference the global variable

Comment: Change `const` to `let` and change `function overWrite(obj)` to `function overWrite()` so that overWrite can modify `obj` in the outer scope.

Comment: @Paulpro That wouldn't work, since `logObj` works with a copy of the `{ foo: '123' }` reference provided by the `logObj(obj)` call. You have to remove both function parameters, so `console.log(obj)` doesn't work with a copy and `obj = { foo: 'bar' }` sets the global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `obj = {foo: 'bar'}` do `obj.foo= 'bar'`

```js
const obj = {
  foo: '123'
};

function logObj(obj) {
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(obj);
  }, 100)
}

function overWrite(obj) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('overwriting')
    obj.foo = 'bar'
  }, 1000);
}

logObj(obj)
overWrite(obj)
```

Comment: can you please explain why ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382427/are-there-pointers-in-javascript/17382443#17382443

Comment: I removed the `obj` from `overWrite()` so that I modify the global object, i.e https://jsfiddle.net/yo15e3bn/ but `logObj` is still showing the old value?

Answer (score 2):

To get a better understanding of what's happening let's rename the variables.

```js
const a = { foo: '123' };

function logObj(b) {
  setInterval(function () {
    console.log(b);
  }, 1000);
}

function overWrite(c) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('overwriting');
    c = { foo: 'bar' };
  }, 5000);
}

logObj(a);
overWrite(a);
```

Variables passed to a function are copies of the primary value.

First you call `logObj` with a copy of the value of `a` (a reference to object `{ foo: '123' }`). This reference will be available as `b` in the function.

Then you call `overWrite` with a copy of the value of `a` (a reference to object `{ foo: '123' }`). This reference will be available as `c` in the function. In the callback you replace the contents of `c` with a new reference. However this does not effect the contents of `a` or `b` and is only available during the function body.

Here is an simplified example:

[image: variable diagram]

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple, change your `const obj` to `var obj = {...}`.

As you can see in [this](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e) article there's a difference when declaring variables with `var`, `const` or `let`.

> const cannot be updated or re-declared

Comment: The issue doesn't have to do with using constants in this case, however that is a good general rule to follow.

Comment: The user expects a different (= changed or updated) object after the timeout runs out. Therefore I clearly think that this is the issue here.

Comment: that is not the case, no. This is about references and not about the scope.