# Can someone explain this piece of Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the ambiguous title, I just didn't know what else to put. Im learning JS and in the video the person does this. [image: JS code]

When he calls the addListAfterKeyPress method at the bottom, why does the function call work? I thought he would have to put in a argument for the  addListAfterKeyPress to take in since it has an event parameter. But in the end the code works perfectly. And also, when can i call a function that takes a parameter without explicitly passing one like how he did it in the picture?

Comment: Look up what `addEventListener()` does.

Comment: it tells the browser to call the function when the event occurs. The browser will call it with arguments then, you don't need to put the arguments here.

Comment: [Don't post code as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/269970)

Comment: The event parameter is passed automatically by the browser because the callback method was passed to the addEventListener method

Comment: `element.addEventListener( eventName, functionName )` this method only need the **names**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a so called callback.

`addListAfterKeypress` at line 30 is not a call to this function, it is just saying, whenever the event `keypress` is raised on this `input` element, call this function.
Who is calling the function is the DOM library, indeed. You just have to pass a pointer to the function to be called.
Even more, the `addListAfterKeypress` function expects an `event` parameter, which will be provided to the function by the DOM library.

I think it is a bit more understanding by looking at an annonymous function there.

```
input.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
   // This will be run whenever the input raises an event of type 'keypress'
   // Here, the DOM library provides me an event parameter
});
```

**Edit on demand**: 
Be aware, I am using ES6 just for comfort.

Suppose having this function

```
const callback = () => {
    console.log(`My callback function is being executed`);
};
```

I will be using `setTimeout` to mock the HTML events. `setTimeout` is a function that expects a callback to execute after `n` milliseconds.
The first parameter is the callback itself, the second is the amount of milliseconds, `n`.
*See  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp*

```
setTimeout(callback, 500); // After 500ms, function callback will be fired
```

Here, I am just passing a pointer to the `setTimeout` function. This pointer must point to a function that will be called by `setTimeout`.

Let's write our own function that takes a callback as a parameter.

```
const callback2 = (number) => {
    console.log('I received this parameter', number);
};

const callbackWrap = (callback, n) => {
    // Here, callback parameter is a function that I can invoke, actually
    console.log('The wrapper will execute the function passed as parameter');
    callback(n);
};
```

Now, we can call the wrapper pointing to the new callback (`callback2`).

```
callbackWrap(callback2, 3);
callbackWrap(callback2, 4);
```

Or, we can define our function directly on the parameter list.
That is, we are passing an annonymous function

```
// p is the parameter of the callback function
callbackWrap(p => {
    // Since callbackWrap will call the function parameter
    // by passing a single parameter,
    // the function I am declaring, expects that parameter
    console.log(`Received ${p} inside the annonymous function`);
}, 'Parameter');
```

So, to summerize a bit, just the same way you can declare a variable (let's say, of type number) and then pass it to a function as a parameter, you can declare a function to pass it the same way.

```
const normalParameter = 30;
const functionParameter = p => console.log('Another callback', p);
callbackWrap(functionParameter, normalParameter);

// Or maybe passing more complex parameters
const anotherParameter = [1, '2', {3: 4}];
callbackWrap(functionParameter, anotherParameter );
```

Hope it clarifies a bit.

Comment: I dont really understand how or why callbacks work. I read the stackoverflow answer on it but I didn't understand too much from it.  Do you think you can give me a simple rundown on it?

Comment: From my understanding, callbacks are used for asynchronous programming. And so you use the callbacks to start a process so that it's ready to be executed immediately after some event. So in the example you posted, ```event``` instructions are being processed in the background and therefore are ready when the ```addEventListener``` function calls it in its own function. Is that accurate or am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: I am typing some chunks of code to explain it. Wait for me

Comment: @Cris Callbacks are not just for async, but often are used for them.

Comment: Good answer but be carefull, JS does not have pointers, that's a bit missleading.

Comment: Well, it does. When you declare `let a = {};`, `a` is a pointer to the heap where an object is stored. If you initialize another variable with `a`, you are just pointing to the same address in memory. Check this tiny test: [Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/9gdqf2jb/1/). Since functions are stored in variables as well, whenever you pass a function as a parameter, you are pointing to the address where the function is stored. So yes, JS has pointers, no matter if we are not able to operate them (like C++, for instance).

Comment: @VRoxa I definitly know what you mean but you can't call this pointers because they arent. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382427/are-there-pointers-in-javascript)