# Trying to pass a name of some existing variable in order to read it's value

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

```
var foo = 10;
var bar = "foo";  // I want bar to be a pointer to the contents of foo
alert(bar);   // Naturally, the alert shows 'foo'
```

How can I setup a pointer to variable foo to let bar show 10 instead of 'foo'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382427/are-there-pointers-in-javascript this might help you

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: `var bar = foo;` ? :D

Comment: I think with a pointer you are talking about referencing ? 
eg - if any change to bar happens, should happen to foo as well.

Comment: There are no pointers (or references) to variables in JS.