# javascript variable scope in this particular instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-upload-file-plugin

In javascript/jQuery, before a file upload plugin is called, a variable is set:

```
doc_type = "q";
```

Then, the plugin is initialized. Within the plugin options is: `onSelect:`, which is called when files are selected. Code looks like this:

```
var doc_type = "q";
$(function(){
    var project_num = $("#pnum").val();
    var uploadObj = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
        url: "upload_files_processor.php",
        method: "POST",
        onSelect: function(){
            doc_type = "W";
            //Or:
            //doc_type = $('#hidden_input').val();  <-- What I really need to do
            return true;
        },
            allowedTypes:"pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,bmp,jpg,png,zip",
        fileName: "myfile",
        formData: {"project_num":project_num,"doc_type":doc_type},
        multiple: true,
        autoSubmit: true,
        showStatusAfterSuccess:false,
        onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr) {
            //Refresh documents table
        },
    });
}); //END document.ready()
```

Problem:

In the upload processor `upload_files_processor.php`, the received `doc_type` value is:

```
$doc_type = $_POST["doc_type"];  // q
```

How can I receive the value `W` ?

References: [heyageek jquery upload file plugin website](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) -- click on *`API & Options`* tab

Comment: `onSelect` happens **after** `formData: {"project_num":project_num,"doc_type":doc_type}` "How can I receive the value W ?" --- just put it in your `formData`?

Comment: You're right, that will work, but that's not what I need to do. The value W must be set in another function (when a particular DIV is clicked). Alternately, a hidden field is updated and that value (W) must be read from that hidden field. Either way will work, so long as W is transferred to the `upload_files_processor.php` (Question updated for clarity - thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, instead of `formData: {"project_num":project_num,"doc_type":doc_type},`
use this:

```
dynamicFormData: function()
{
    return {
        project_num: $("#pnum").val(),
        doc_type: $('#hidden_input').val()
    };
},
```

And remove the lines `var doc_type = "q";` and `var project_num = $("#pnum").val()`

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Advanced](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) tab of the api. There is an option called `dynamicFormData` which is executed and [**appears**](https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/blob/master/js/jquery.uploadfile.js#L507) to be appended to the formdata right before sending.

```
dynamicFormData: function() {
    var data ={"doc_type":doc_type };
    return data;
},
```

This is what you need because `doc_type` will be evaluated right before it is sent rather than when it is created.

*IF this works.  I don't really have a way to test it*

Comment: I missed the obvious, thanks for the answer. I have asked the author (Ravi) to add this option to the API & Options section of his website, and I look forward to reviewing other answers you have contributed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do it this way:

```
var formData = {
    project_num: null,
    doc_type: "q"
};

$(function() {

    formData.project_num = $("#pnum").val();

    var uploadObj = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
        url: "upload_files_processor.php",
        method: "POST",
        onSelect: function(){
            formData.doc_type = $('#hidden_input').val();
        },
        allowedTypes:"pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,bmp,jpg,png,zip",
        fileName: "myfile",
        formData: formData,
        multiple: true,
        autoSubmit: true,
        showStatusAfterSuccess:false,
        onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr) {
            //Refresh documents table
        },
    });
});
```

I am not sure how the plugin works internally. If it serializes `formData` into some internal format, you could run into problems. However if it is simply setting the internal `formData` attribute to point to a provided object, then this should work. The reference to `formData` remains the same; you're just modifying a property of the object that is used.

Comment: I've tested this method and it works.  Probably best to use the `dynamicFormData` setting since it's there (your code will be more robust).  But it's worth making sure you understand why Vivin Paliath's suggestion can work.  If you don't, have a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231868/pointers-in-javascript