# Store the location of an element in an array, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reinforcement-learning

## ***Short question***

***(maybe a bit to complex)***

I have a *very* complex **array**. I need to store the "*location*" (in c it would be a **pointer**) of my last *update* on the array for technical reasons (see below).

How may I do that in **pure JS**?

---

## ***Long question***

***(long but clear)***

I am working on a kind of **reinforcement learning** and I have a problem with the *array* which I use to *store* what my system *just learned*.

### Description of my array

My program is *learning* (or working on) the tic tac toe game. It stores what it learned on an array described below:

```js
var learningArray = [
    [/* What has been played? (Object)*/, /* What has been play following this turn? (Array)*/],
    [/* What has been played? (Object)*/, /* What has been play following this turn? (Array)*/],
    [/* What has been played? (Object)*/, /* What has been play following this turn? (Array)*/],
    [/* What has been played? (Object)*/, /* What has been play following this turn? (Array)*/],
    [/* What has been played? (Object)*/, /* What has been play following this turn? (Array)*/],
    [/* What has been played? (Object)*/, /* What has been play following this turn? (Array)*/],
    [/* What has been played? (Object)*/, /* What has been play following this turn? (Array)*/],
    [/* What has been played? (Object)*/, /* What has been play following this turn? (Array)*/],
    [/* What has been played? (Object)*/, /* What has been play following this turn? (Array)*/]
];
```

The array is composed of *smaller arrays*. Each *smaller array* is composed of **two elements**:

- The description of the turn (what has been played and where);
- The following turns using the same structures (two elements, the first stores the data and the second the others turn of play during the game).

I *update* my array following *each turn*. So normally, it **stores every turn on the game**. After several games, it may store **every possibility** of each turn of the game (next I would compute the probability of winning).

***NOTE:*** of course, my array first has nine elements because there are nine squares on the game grid of the tic tac toe game.

### The problem

Suppose I have just updated an *element* of my array. I need to **store** the **location** of this *element* to write the **following turn at the next update**.

I love c++ and c because **pointers** are pretty useful and simple to use. The solution to this problem in c is to define a **pointer** **to the last element updated**. Easy and simple.

However, JS does **not support pointers** ([or everything is done to think it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231868/pointers-in-javascript)). No solution here...

How may I resolve my problem?

---

*Tell me if you have some questions or comments*

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have pointers. Why can't you just use the array index?

Comment: In JS Objects are always 'pointed' to so you can just keep the Object as ' ' 'lastUpdatedObject' ? This will need to be outside of the scope of the updating function itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand what you want to achieve but what about setting up a simple global variable which holds the location inside your array?