# Create Array reference with element index instead of value copy

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

The following initialization of `b` seems to copy array data from `a` instead of referencing it, as intended:

```js
let a = [0,1];
let b = [a[0], 2];
a[0]=3;
console.log(b);
```

The output is `0,2`.

- Why is the output not `3,2`?
- How can `b[0]` be initialized with a reference to `a[0]` so that it reflects changes to `a`?
- If that's not possible, what are the alternatives?
- Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitive values, such as numbers, booleans, and strings are copied by value, because they're immutable; conversely, objects, arrays, and functions are copied by reference.

See also: [Primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

This can be demonstrated with a simple example:

```js
let a = [{foo: 0},{bar: 1}];
let b = [a[0], 2];
a[0].foo = 3;
console.log(b);
```

If you want to copy by reference, you need to copy the whole array, instead of individual values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign by reference. It means that variable `b` stores reference to variable `a` and variable `a` stores reference to array `[0, 1]`. It means any time you are editing any of variable `a` or `b`, then the array `[0, 1]` will be changed :

```
let a = [0,1];
let b = a;
a[0] = 3;
b[1] = 2;
```

An example:

```js
let a = [0,1];
let b = a;
a[0]=3;
b[1] = 2;
document.querySelector("div").innerText = b;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Value vs. Reference](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

**UPDATE:**

You can get `indexOf` array to be edited and then just edit number by index:

```js
let a = [0,1];
let b = [a[0], 2];
let index = b.indexOf(a[0]);
let valueToSet = 3;
a[0] = valueToSet;
b[index] = valueToSet;
console.log(`a is`, a);
console.log(`b is`, b);
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I create a reference to `a[0]`? According to your link, that might not be possible ("non-primitive-value"). Then, what are the alternatives? The duplicate reference `b === a` does not solve my problem; `a` needs to be a "child" of `b`...

Comment: Thanks again. Simply put, your edit is just copying the data to both Arrays. That's not what I was hoping for - however, it seems there may not be a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

It is copying the value only, not the reference.

Technically once you add into array `b` the value of `a[0]`, you are not copying its reference, just the value. So later if you modify elements in array `a` then it won't affect the values of array `b`.

It works exactly like using a variable - using `elem` below:

```js
let a = [0,1];
let elem = a[0]; // value type, not copying the reference
let b = [elem, 2];
a[0]=3;
document.querySelector("div").innerText = b;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I hope this explains!

Comment: That's exactly my problem! But why is this a copy? And how can I achieve what I intended?

Answer (score 0):

As suspected,

```
let b = [a[0], 2];
```

initializes `b` with a copy of the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) in `a` instead of referencing it, so later changes to the item are not (automatically) reflected in `b`.

Unfortunately I was not able to find this behavior in the MDN JavaScript reference docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures.
See [StepUp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905542/1619432) for a link to some information.

I am still hoping there might be a way (maybe [Pointers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231868/pointers-in-javascript)?).

In the meantime, simply defining the variable(s) again ("update", "redefine") works around my problem - it's "better" than copying to both arrays only in that it's the simplest way to update a number of dependent variables:

```js
let a = [0,1];
let b = [a[0], 2];
a[0]=3;
b = [a[0], 2];
console.log(b);  // [3,2]
```

This is the minimal case, it can of course be wrapped in a function (`return b;`) to simplify the (re-)definition of many variables.