# JS | How to make one variable a link to another

Tags: javascript

Instead of just assigning/copying the value of var b to var a via `a = b;`,

I‘d like to **make `a` ‚link‘ to `b`**, so that *when a is changed, actually b is changed* and *when a is used, actually b is used*, so to say. Is that possible?

(You could call it a reference).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well that is not really possible with regular variables. Could do something with objects. If we see some actual code we might be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231868/pointers-in-javascript)

Comment: [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects ?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask] since we are "LovingGreatQuestions"

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli That sounds like it, thank you, i will look into it. You may consider posting this as an actual answer.

Comment: That's a very bad idea. You want to divert an established and recognized functioning on a specificity of this language. Sorry, but this is something that really pisses me off. think about code maintenance, think about those who will have to reread this kind of code and whom you will trap with this kind of feature, think about the bugs that this can cause and the possible disasters that can occur during execution,...

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with using objects?

```js
const a = {
  current: 5,
}

const b = a

b.current = 10

console.log(a, b)
```

Comment: Would be an option, if there was no reason why my code uses arrays. So i will wait for the ‚yes/no, if yes: how‘ answer.

Comment: You should show your code