# Is it possible to change variable value inside this function?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Is it possible to change the value of `p` inside the `mf` function via the call to `up` function passing it the `p` variable?

Theoretically it should be possible because `javascript` passes references of variables to functions, I think, by default

```
function up(p){
    p++;
    console.log('p from up function: ' + p);
}

function mf(){
    let p = 15;
    console.log('p from mf function: ' + p);
    return () => {
        console.log('p from arrow function before: ' + p);
        up(p);
        console.log('p from arrow function after: ' + p);
    }
}

let tf = mf()
tf()
```

After the call to `tf()` function I expected it to increase the value of `p` inside `mf` function but every time `up` function is receiving the same value of `p` that is `15`

Comment: It doesnt pass by reference on ints (and other primitive types)

Comment: JavaScript is a call by value/copy language. There’s no reference semantics. Pass an object and it’s reference/pointer is copied

Comment: @GetSet so I should create a wrapper object around `p` and then pass around that object to other functions? Or is there another way

Comment: You can also return the increased value and assign it back to `p`.

Comment: That's what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43862253/446594) is suggesting/demonstrating, dunno if that solution is "clean" tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to put p into an object, and pass the object.

This is sometimes known as the "value holder" pattern.

```js
function up(o){
  o.p++;
  console.log('p from up function: ' + o.p);
}

function mf(){
  let o = {p: 15};
  console.log('p from mf function: ' + o.p);
  return () => {
    console.log('p from arrow function before: ' + o.p);
    up(o);
    console.log('p from arrow function after: ' + o.p);
  }
}

let tf = mf()
tf()
```